# Android: Lock components in place with soft keyboard

Tags: android, user-interface, textview

The soft keyboard moves a TextView object up with it, (adjusting), and this causes the TextView to overlay another TextView that I'd like to be able to see.

I need a way to lock this TextView *specifically*, so that the keyboard will overlay it. But only that component. I do not want to pan the entire window, just this one, single, TextView object.

Is there a way to tell the TextView, "Dammit bro, don't move with the keyboard" programmatically?

To be honest, I'd also be willing to settle for keeping all of the components from moving, allowing the keyboard to overlay all of them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you look at [`android:windowSoftInputMode`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)

Comment: Yes, but that applies to the whole window. I only want to keep ONE of the components from moving. The rest of them are OK with panning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to answer this, the basic answer is that there is no way to do this.

You can try `android:windowSoftInputMode` and use "`adjustNothing,`" but apparently this doesn't work (and it didn't work for me either.)

Other than that, you're limited to `adjustPan` and `adjustResize` for the soft input repositioning, so you'll have to make your UI accommodate this huge issue.