# EditText moves entire gui when new lines are added, how to stop that?

Tags: android, android-layout

**What's the problem:**
[Example with copy pasting text (Video)](https://youtu.be/6Iss7eXI0sQ)
[Example with adding new lines (Video)](https://youtu.be/OLaVBDd6nEM)

**I tried:**
-Changing what is hooked up to what
-Making EditText take entire layout
-Checking when new lines are added, for main layout or gui element layouts change (no, they aren't changing)

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ultimatecoder">



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >


        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"


    android:id="@+id/mainConstraint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/codeTextBoxConstraint"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/openedFilesScrollView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:background="@color/colorButtonsTopBar"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/codeTextBox"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/colorBackground"
            android:backgroundTint="#00FFFFFF"
            android:ems="10"
            android:fontFamily="@font/consola"
            android:gravity="start|top"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:textColorHighlight="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textColorLink="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/openedFilesScrollView" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/topBarConstraint"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/openedFilesButton"
            android:layout_width="201dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
            android:background="@color/colorButtonsTopBar"
            android:text="Show Open Files"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomBarConstraint"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Additional options used:**

```kotlin
codeTextBox.setHorizontallyScrolling(true)
codeTextBox.setPadding(0,0,0,0)
```

Comment: Pleas post screenshots or to youtube

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found similiar question with anwser ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21898018/android-lock-components-in-place-with-soft-keyboard))

adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to activity solved the problem!

**new activity_main.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ultimatecoder">



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

        >


        <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:name=".MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```